# How can nginx report empty `ssl_protocol` when successfully handling a query with TLS?

Tags: https, nginx

I have an `nginx` proxy which is handling requests in a server block like this (redacted):

```
http {
    log_format testformat '[$time_local] [$remote_addr] [$ssl_protocol] [$status] $request_method:$request_uri';

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name my.test.server;
        # ssl config here - only TLS 1.2 is enabled
    
        access_log /var/log/nginx/ testformat;

        ...
    }
}
```

The access log format includes both `$status` and `$ssl_protocol`. As I would expect, almost every entry reports protocol `TLSv1.2`:

```
[06/Feb/2024:03:46:40 +0000] [10.150.66.19] [TLSv1.2] [200] POST:/blah/somewhere (User-Agent-string)
```

But some log entries look like this:

```
[06/Feb/2024:13:50:21 +0000] [10.139.11.2] [-] [200] POST:/blah/somewhere (User-Agent-string)
```

I don't understand how `ssl_protocol` can be empty. The `POST` was apparently successful. Surely this means that the client must have established a TLS connection correctly? If so then how can it have an empty protocol?